# How to access a pointer array in a function in c

Tags: c

I have a pointer array then I try to access the value of the pointer array in the function but it crashes.
Why and how can I access the values pls?

```
char* test[3][1024]={"Trans1","Trans2","Trans3"};
creerBlock(test,3, NULL,1);
extern BLOCK* creerBlock(char* transactions[], int nbTransactions, char *pHashCodePrec, int numBloc)
```

I tried:

```
printf("%s", *transactions[0]);
```

And:

```
printf("%s", transactions[0]);
```

Comment: Doesn't your compiler already warn at the very first line?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please turn on all warnings in your compiler. For GCC use `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. Then if you get a warning, read it carefully.

Comment: `char* test[3][1024]` -> `char* test[3]`. Then `printf("%s", transactions[0]);`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
printf("%s", *transactions);
```

for the first element 
and

```
printf("%s", *(transactions+1));
```

for the second element.
Because trasactions has a type char *

Comment: If you have another type try to change the %s if you used in another contexte

Answer (score 0):

Since **char*** can be an array, by writing **char* test[3][1024]** you are creating a triple dimensionned array. You should choose between **char* test[3]** and **char test[3][1024]**.

Then you can use :

```
printf("%s", transactions[0]);
```